# Eliminating the duplication of methods

Tags: go

Is it possible to refactor the following code to eliminate the duplication?

I want my GameObject implement the logic for "update" task invoking different update handlers (like my "AfterUpdate"). The current version works, but  there are two implementations of "Update" and they are equal.
AfterUpdate invoked on GameObject should operate on its properties, AfterUpdate invoked on HeroGameObject should have access to HeroGameObject's properties (like "health" for example).

What can I do better? Thank you.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Point struct {
    x, y int
}

///////////////////////
type GameObject struct {
    Point
    title       string
    status      int
    ticks       float32
    spriteIndex int
}

func (g *GameObject) Update() {

    if g.ticks == 0 {
       
        g.spriteIndex++
        g.AfterUpdate()
    }
}

func (g *GameObject) AfterUpdate() {
    g.status = 0 //suppose it does something meaningful
    fmt.Println("GameObject afterUpdate handler invoked")
}

///////////////////////
type HeroGameObject struct {
    GameObject
    health float32
}

func (h *HeroGameObject) Update() {

    if h.ticks == 0 {
      
        h.spriteIndex++
        h.AfterUpdate()
    }
}

func (h *HeroGameObject) AfterUpdate() {
    h.health-- //suppose it does something meaningful but *different*, using its own properties, for example "health"
    fmt.Println("HeroGameObject afterUpdate handler invoked")
}

///////////////////////
func main() {

    gameObject := &GameObject{
        Point: Point{
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
        },
        title:       "dummy object",
        status:      0,
        ticks:       0,
        spriteIndex: 0,
    }

    heroObject := &HeroGameObject{
        GameObject: GameObject{
            Point: Point{
                x: 0,
                y: 0,
            },
            title:       "hero object",
            status:      0,
            ticks:       0,
            spriteIndex: 0,
        },
        health: 0,
    }

    gameObject.Update()
    heroObject.Update()
}
```

The output:

> GameObject afterUpdate handler invoked
>
> HeroGameObject afterUpdate handler invoked

**UPDATED**
I've come up with the following solution and I wonder what do you think:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Point struct {
    x, y int
}

///////////////////////
type IHandler interface {
    afterUpdate()
}

type GameObject struct {
    Point
    title       string
    status      int
    ticks       float32
    spriteIndex int
    handler IHandler
}

func (g *GameObject) SetHandler(h IHandler) {
    g.handler = h
}

func (g *GameObject) Update() {

    if g.ticks == 0 {

        g.spriteIndex++
        if g.handler != nil {
            g.handler.afterUpdate()
        }
    }
}

//actually it is IHandler specific implementation number one
func (g *GameObject) afterUpdate() {
    g.status = 0 //suppose it does something meaningful
    fmt.Println("GameObject afterUpdate handler invoked")
}

///////////////////////
type HeroGameObject struct {
    GameObject
    health float32
}

// note, this method is commented out
/*
func (h *HeroGameObject) Update() {

    if h.ticks == 0 {

        h.spriteIndex++
        h.AfterUpdate()
    }
}*/

//actually it is IHandler specific implementation number two
func (h *HeroGameObject) afterUpdate() {
    h.health-- //suppose it does something meaningful but *different*, using its own properties, for example "health"
    fmt.Println("HeroGameObject afterUpdate handler invoked")
}

///////////////////////
func main() {

    gameObject := &GameObject{
        Point: Point{
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
        },
        title:       "dummy object",
        status:      0,
        ticks:       0,
        spriteIndex: 0,
    }
    gameObject.SetHandler(gameObject) //!

    heroObject := &HeroGameObject{
        GameObject: GameObject{
            Point: Point{
                x: 0,
                y: 0,
            },
            title:       "hero object",
            status:      0,
            ticks:       0,
            spriteIndex: 0,
        },
        health: 0,
    }
    heroObject.SetHandler(heroObject) //!

    gameObject.Update()
    heroObject.Update()
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/GIwOknSSzx

Is it okay to have "gameObject.SetHandler(gameObject)"?

Comment: No. Inheritance based programming will fail in Go.

Comment: yes, I know that. My question is what can I do in this situation.

Comment: I think the question is fine but Invariably some one is going to tell you to post questions like this on the codereview stackexchange.

Comment: @Adam Gent, yes, the question is fine since it is about how to transpose one language feature into another, and the provided code is only a use case example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using flag function and base interface, like this?

```
type BaseGameObject interface {
    Ticks() int
    IncSpriteIndex()
    AfterUpdate()
}

func UpdateGameObject(o BaseGameObject) {
    if o.Ticks() == 0 {
        o.IncSpriteIndex()
        o.AfterUpdate()
    }
}

func (o *GameObject) Ticks() int {
    return o.ticks
}

func (o *GameObject) IncSpriteIndex() {
    o.spriteIndex++
}
```

Comment: Yeah, flat function UpdateGameObject() has common knownledge how to update a (Base)GameObject.  It is not belong to any types.

Comment: is there a better way than using a standalone function? yes, it works.

Comment: @varnie Not sure if it's better, but you can expand them both with a "GameUpdater" type which holds this logic, see this example: http://play.golang.org/p/rqZb4BbER-